# Call function from span by icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some issues with this code here:

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery("#check_in").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
            minDate: 0,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                jQuery( "#check_out" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            },
        });

        jQuery("#check_out").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
            minDate: 0,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                jQuery( "#check_in" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            },
        });
    });
    </script>';
```

```html
<div class="row_field field_text">
  <label class="label_title">'.__('Check Out','tfuse').'</label>
   <input type="text" name="check_out" value="" id="check_out">
    <span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>
  </div>
```

the problem is that I want, when I am clicking on span icon to call the function like it dose from input fields. if someone has any solution please help
Sorry but I am not good at Java & jQuery so pleased if you could show me the answer with HTML tags.

thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you want the `datepicker()` to be initialized when someone clicks on `.icon-calendar`? if so... check in or check out? if not, what function do you want to be called?

Comment: Either way I suppose... `$(".icon-calendar").click( myFunction );` is how you have a click on the span call whatever function.

Comment: Also it looks like you are trying to do something you could already do with build in jquery ui functionality... look [**here**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) and click to view source. There are properties you can use to show the image and choose a certain image and such.

Comment: thanks for reply, I have seen build in jquery ui functionality but I don't understand how to connect this to my DB. I bought one template fro wordpres and I want to make this kind of change on the template. I have searched a lot how to solve this problem but the problem is that I have no basis knowledge of javascript programming at this moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to get the input by it's id rather than position in the DOM. This way if there are changes made in the future, your javascript is still guaranteed to work (assuming the id isn't the thing being changed).

```
$(".icon-calendar").click(function() {
    $("#check_out").focus();
});
```

But I do agree with dfsq about using the built in configuration for datepicker being the best choice.

Comment: wow thank you so much!!! the solution is at this moment is" $("#check_out").focus();"... everithing is working!!!! thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

As noticed in comments by @smerny jQuery UI datepicker has an option to show a calendar icon. So this is what you can do. However what datepicker code does is basically bind a click event on this icon which simply puts a focus into corresponding input text field. Hence your second option: if you still want to use your own icon (and maybe you want different HTML structure for it) all you need to do is to focus input field on icon click. Maybe like this:

```
$('.icon-calendar').click(function() {
    $(this).prev(':text').focus();
});
```

**However**, I would go with configuration option better.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2g9ovncg/

Comment: Thank you for the reply, you explain me pretty well, but I have still erred, so can I send you the file that is written all the code? so, to solve the problem, because I am trying to solve this problem more than 4 days :-D here is the file: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/f9f43b0484d7/search_rooms.php chek it out if you can :-)

Comment: It will be better if you post your code in fiddle or create a separate question.